# Load dynamic php generated page in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a simple HTML, where on a  tag i have `onmouseover="loadQueryResults();"`

Here is a function:

```
function loadQueryResults(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var data = [];
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (target) {
        var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);

        }
    }
    //window.open("racun.php?name="+data) THIS WORKS
    //window.alert("racun.php?name=" + data) THIS WORKS
    //document.writeln(data);
    final=data.toString();
    //document.writeln(final); THIS ALSO WORKS
    stranica="racun.php?name="+final;
    $( "#DisplayDiv" ).load(stranica); //THIS DOESNT WORK---WHY???
    $( "#DisplayDiv" ).load("racun.php"); //THIS however WORKS!
}
```

Question is, why when i include arguments in php page i want to load, nothing happens?

Comment: Did you checked you racun.php script ? Does it work in browser when you call it with a parameter ?

Comment: It does. And it works with window.open() function...it just doesnt with $("div").load()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think cells[i].innerHTML has space or characters that not allowed in url!

u should use this function to filter 'final' variable:

```
final = encodeURIComponent( data.toString() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass params according to jQuery docs:

```
$( "#DisplayDiv" ).load("racun.php", {name: data.toString() });
```

And "final" looks like reserved word